# Partitioning in Linux with Parted

Tags: linux, partitioning, alignment

I’m trying to create a new partition in Linux with [Parted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Parted). I start Parted as below (at root).

```
parted -a optimal /dev/sda
```

Below is the current partition table.

```
Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  211MB   210MB   primary   ext4            boot
 2      211MB   10.7GB  10.5GB  primary   ext4
 3      10.7GB  15.9GB  5243MB  primary   linux-swap(v1)
 4      15.9GB  150GB   134GB   extended                  lba
```

I am getting the below warning when creating the partition.

```
(parted) mkpart extended 10957 149504
Warning: You requested a partition from 11.0GB to 150GB.
The closest location we can manage is 15.9GB to 150GB.
Is this still acceptable to you?
Yes/No? yes
Warning: WARNING: the kernel failed to re-read the partition table on /dev/sda (Device or resource busy).  As a result, it may not reflect all of your changes until after reboot.
(parted) mkpart logical ext4 10957 149504
Warning: You requested a partition from 11.0GB to 150GB.
The closest location we can manage is 15.9GB to 150GB.
Is this still acceptable to you?
Yes/No? yes
Warning: The resulting partition is not properly aligned for best performance.
Ignore/Cancel?
```

Why is Parted not using the optimal alignment?

Answer (score 1):

Try this way (as root):

```
fdisk /dev/sda
```

fdisk session:

```
WARNING: DOS-compatible mode is deprecated. It's strongly recommended to
         switch off the mode (command 'c') and change display units to
         sectors (command 'u').

Command (m for help): n
First cylinder (2905-10011, default 2905):
Using default value 2905
Last cylinder, +cylinders or +size{K,M,G} (2905-10011, default 10011): +20M

Command (m for help): t
Partition number (1-6): 6
Hex code (type L to list codes): 83

Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/sda: 82.3 GB, 82348277760 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 10011 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0001501c

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          26      204800   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2              26        2637    20971520   83  Linux
/dev/sda3            2637        2898     2097152   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda4            2898       10011    57138861+   5  Extended
/dev/sda5            2898        2904       51852+  83  Linux
/dev/sda6            2905        2908       32098+  83  Linux

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered!

Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.

WARNING: Re-reading the partition table failed with error 16: Device or resource busy.
The kernel still uses the old table. The new table will be used at
the next reboot or after you run partprobe(8) or kpartx(8)
Syncing disks.
```

Where:

- `sda` is your hard disk
- `n` means  add a new partition
- `t` means  change a partition's system id
- `p` means  print the partition table
- `w` means  write table to disk and exit